Multi-yield mechanism in C#
I have a question over on Code Review SE where I'm struggling to work out how to refactor my enumerator method to be less of a complete mess.
I think part of the problem is I can't work out how to call other methods from inside it and have them yield results without having to wrap that inner call inside a foreach and yeild out the items one by one.
Is there any way to do some sort of multi-yield in C# so that this would work?
    private IEnumerable<int> Outer()
    {
        yield return 0;
        yield return Inner(); // Some sort of multi-yield
        yield return 5;
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<int> Inner()
    {
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;
        yield return 4;
    }

I know I can do this, but this isn't what I'm looking for as by the time I've done this a few times, my refactored version wouldn't be much better:
    private IEnumerable<int> Outer()
    {
        yield return 0;
        foreach (int i in Inner())
        {
            yield return i;
        }
        yield return 5;
    }


Note: I've since decided that the answer to my refactoring question was that I don't need an Enumerable in that case. However, this question is still valid in-case if I wanted to expose something like that as an enumerable from a library or something. It just isn't the best option for the linked problem. I'll leave it linked for extra context though.

What you're doing is pretty much the best way. You might look into LINQ's Union or Concat methods for some cases, though.

yield can only produce one item at a time, there is no "yield multiple" or something like that. Either use the foreach approach, or e.g. create an intermediary List<int> because that supports AddRange().

What you're looking for can't be done. The elements of Inner can't be known without enumerating it. You could avoid yield and do something like return Inner().Prepend(0).Append(5), or return Enumerable.Empty<int>().Append(0).Concat(Inner()).Append(5); but it's the same thing except that LINQ methods are doing it, and there are more enumerables involved.

@PeterB While strictly correct, putting a temporary list would materialize the whole sequence, defeating the purpose of yield return in the first place.

@madreflection - might put a feature request in because I think this could be useful. Being able to have an inner enumerator seems like something that shouldn't be completely out there as a concept

It would still be doing the same thing, but now hidden from the developer. The "bang for the buck" isn't there, and I'm sure you're not the first to think about it. There's nothing wrong with the loop to iterate Inner().

Well sure, but a whole lot of things being added to the language are essentially syntactic sugar these days. You might be right though that there wouldn't be enough value for it to be worth developing

There is some proposal somewhere on the official github repo to introduce some kind of yield return all that should do exactly what you ask. But its a proposal still :(

I guess it would come under this one? https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/378

I'm struggling to work out how to refactor my enumerator method to be less of a complete mess - do whatever makes your code easier to read and/or maintain. For example, a method similar to Inner() might make sense with a proper name indicating it's purpose, and if it will would be reused somewhere else.

@RuiJarimba - I have actually gone and just refactored it to not use an enumerable because it's unnecessary in my context. However, it left me with this question

I highly doubt this is the true solution, as your code example is probably simplified, but for something like your code example, producing numbers in sequence there is Enumerable.Range(start, count) which can then be dumped to your collection choice as that is returning IEnumerable

Nesting enumerators sounds like a nightmare to be honest. If I do Outer().Take(3) am I supposed to expect [0,1,2] or [0, [1,2,3,4], 5]? To complicate matters, a newer/inexperienced dev using var heavily may not even recognize that its not the expected flat vs jagged array. I do not even want to be handed a situation like this. I highly advise against opening such a feature request...

@Narish - [0, 1, 2] would be what I'm going for. The example in this question is academic. If you look at the linked question over on Code Review you'll see the actual code

@ScottishTapWater Right so we would have to re-implement LINQ by a lot to be able to go from its status quo behavior to LINQ being able to parse when it needs to treat a jagged array as a flat array...Way too much is being black boxed

From looking at your code, I am not an expert in reflection at all, but I see nothing wrong with that foreach loop happening there. Complexity is also a moot point here....we need to iterate

@Narish - Well nah, you'd use a different keyword wouldn't you

Perhaps you need to write a sourcecode transformation that is done during compile, so you can actually write something like //yieldmany return Inner() in your code, and your generator picks it up and transforms it to foreach(var v in Inner()) yield return v on the fly

@flackoverstow - This is one of the few times I really wish C# had proper macros

You can not do better if you keep some yield return statements at the top level method. But if all yield return statements are at the leaf methods, you can use IEnumerable.Concat:
    private IEnumerable<int> Outer()
    {
        return Inner1().Concat(Inner2()).Concat(Inner3());
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> Inner1()
    {
        yield return 0;
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<int> Inner2()
    {
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;
        yield return 4;
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> Inner3()
    {
        yield return 5;
    }


Would this not force enumeration of the whole thing immediately thus defeating the point?

@ScottishTapWater Fair question, but the good news is no, Linq methods like Concat() on IEnumerable are well designed on this respect. What materializes the enumerable are methods like ToList() or ToArray().

Working example: https://onlinegdb.com/ACtXOoC9Y

@ScottishTapWater actually not a worry, because they yield themselves so they only really "do anything" when the result of the e.g. concat is enumerated. Check out the source code at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs (or on github for .net core, bt it's unlikely to be substatnially different)
